# Ubuntu Windows Subsystem /mnt/c not working

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have added my folder to /mnt/c but still nothing showing.. this is so frustrating, the number of hours I have wasted. Any ideas please superuser community?

Comment: What do you mean by "add my folder"? All existing folders on the `C:` drive should be there already, but `mkdir` should be able to create new directories, bearing in mind that you need special permissions to create root folders on `C:`.

Comment: The only way you can access folders that aren't a part of Ubuntu is to find them via /mnt/c.. You cannot make any changes whilst in Windows e.g. copy a file to /home. (I only just saw your comment)

Comment: I assumed you knew that `/mnt/c` was how you access Windows `C:`; in contrast, `/home` is located in one of several places, depending on the revision (on my Win10-1709 it is in `"%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs"\`), though it's inadvisable to modify the root file-system from Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the command `ls -a`

Comment: Okay, I get it. This is just a place for Ubuntu to look for folders in my C drive, I can't put a new folder in /mnt/c and access it.